# MariaDB limit value of column

Tags: mariadb, database-schema

I want to limit the value of the column `limited_column`, where `0 >= limited_column <= 100` SQL side, on MariaDB

I've tried creating a trigger on `INSERT` ad `UPDATE` as such:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `limited_column` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
[...]
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `limited_column_check_on_insert_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE dummy,baddataflag INT;
  SET baddataflag = 0;
  IF NEW.limited_column > 100 THEN
    SET baddataflag = 1;
  END IF;
  IF NEW.limited_column < 0 THEN
    SET baddataflag = 1;
  END IF;
  IF baddataflag = 1 THEN
    SELECT CONCAT('Cannot INSERT new value because limited_column is > 100, value was ',NEW.limited_column)
    INTO dummy FROM information_schema.tables;
  END IF;
END; $$
CREATE TRIGGER `limited_column_check_on_update_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE dummy,baddataflag INT;
  SET baddataflag = 0;
  IF NEW.limited_column > 100 THEN
    SET baddataflag = 1;
  END IF;
  IF NEW.limited_column < 0 THEN
    SET baddataflag = 1;
  END IF;
  IF baddataflag = 1 THEN
    SELECT CONCAT('Cannot UPDATE new value because limited_column is > 100, value was ',NEW.limited_column)
    INTO dummy FROM information_schema.tables;
  END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is what I get if I try inserting a new user when limited_column > 100 (limited_column > 100 works):

```sql
MariaDB [NameOfADatabase]> INSERT INTO users (username,user_id,limited_column,[...]) VALUES ('testestes',1,1000,[...]);
ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row
MariaDB [NameOfADatabase]> INSERT INTO users (username,user_id,limited_column,[...]) VALUES ('testestes',2,100,[...]);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

Any ideas on what I can do to make this more graceful?

This is running on 10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Perhaps [`CHECK`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/) instead of `TRIGGER`, assuming you are using at least 10.2.1.

Comment: @RickJames I'm running 10.1.38 unfortunately. I tried the [Numeric constraints and comparisons Example](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/#examples) in the documentation you provided and did not get the same errors that were shown.

Comment: I believe that `CHECK` is syntactically _recognized_, but _ignored_ in 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to `10.3.15` was the best solution for this, as I can use the `CHECK` option. Thanks to @RickJames for the info about the update.

Here's the Schema I'm using that works:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `limited_column` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
[...]
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  CHECK (limited_column<=100)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Here's the output I get:

```sql
MariaDB [NameOfADatabase]> INSERT INTO users (username,user_id,limited_column,[...]) VALUES ('test1',1,100,[...]);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.016 sec)

MariaDB [NameOfADatabase]> INSERT INTO users (username,user_id,limited_column,[...]) VALUES ('test2',2,101,[...]);
ERROR 4025 (23000): CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `NameOfADatabase`.`users`
```